# ReactJS - Dynamically updating HTML when API returns [Solved]

Tags: reactjs, axios

**[Solved]** I needed to reference `matchInfo.Match.length` to render the html correctly

I am trying to render some html when an array gets populated from an API call.
Currently, my array `matchInfo` is getting populated with the correct data, however, the HTML does not update.

What I want to happen is once I get the data back from the backend its rendered in the html.

Thanks

```
export default function NRL() {

const [week, setWeek] = useState();
const [season, setSeason] = useState();
const [matchInfo, setMatchInfo] = useState([])

function handleButtonClick() {
    console.log('getting data: Week: ' + week + ' Season: ' + season) 
    axios.get('/nrl/', {
        params: {week, season}
    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        setMatchInfo((matchInfo) => response.data)
    })
}

return (
    <>
        <div className="page-title">
            <h1>NRL</h1>
        </div>
        
        <div className="input-fields">
            <input className="userIn"
            placeholder="Enter Round"
            name="weekIn" 
            value={week}
            onChange={(e) => setWeek(e.target.value)}/>
            
            <input className="userIn"
            placeholder="Enter Season"
            name="seasonIn" 
            value={season}
            onChange={(e) => setSeason(e.target.value)}/>

            <button onClick={() => handleButtonClick()}>Get Data</button>  
        </div>

        {matchInfo.length > 0 && (
            <div className="display-match-info">
                {matchInfo.map((item, i) => (
                    <p>{item.date}</p>
                )                    
                )}
            </div>
        )}
    </>
)}
```

Comment: How are you verifying that matchInfo is getting updated correctly?  What value shows for this variable in the React dev tool?  Also, does your component rerender after handleButtonClick runs (i.e. I know the UI doesn't update how you expect, but for example if you console.log("rendering") in your component function do you get "rendering" in the console?

Comment: Hello, If add console.log(matchInfo) after setting it it get the data in the console.

Comment: I am a very silly man, turns out I was miss referencing my object. I should have been checking the length of matchInfo.Match

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you pass a function setMatchInfo, rather than passing the value.

Try `setMatchInfo(response.data)`  instead.

Comment: The function version isn't necessary in this case, but I don't see why it wouldn't work as is.

Comment: Yep you're right, sorry I answered a bit fast.

Comment: This didnt seem to make any change.